# Исключение - StopIteration

Tags: python, исключения, итераторы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как поместить StopIteration в исключение.

Например: Эмуляция for через while

Мой код следующий:

```
n = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

iterator = n.__iter__()


while True:
    try:
        print(next(iterator))
    except SropIteration:
        print('Итератор опустошен')
```

Но при запуске сначала выходит следующая ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Nikita.Uvaliyev.KPI\PycharmProjects\python-ds\27_Iterators_and_generators\practice\while_like_for.py",
> line 8, in 
> print(next(iterator)) StopIteration
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Nikita.Uvaliyev.KPI\PycharmProjects\python-ds\27_Iterators_and_generators\practice\while_like_for.py",
> line 9, in 
> except SropIteration: NameError: name 'SropIteration' is not defined

После ошибки уже выводятся объекты итератора

Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте `SropIteration` на `StopIteration`...

```py
n = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

iterator = iter(n)

while True:
    try:
        print(next(iterator))
    except StopIteration:
        print('Итератор опустошен')
        break
```

Comment: Так стыдно за свою невнимательность мне не было никогда :))) спасибо большое :)

Comment: @Peace_DOS, Используйте нормальные IDE для написания кода. Там такие ляпы автоматически подсвечиваются. Я, к примеру, использую PyCharm

Comment: в данном случае тоже PyCharm, подсветка была, но при нажатии на исправление выходил вариант с созданием класса, в принципе из-за этого и благодаря невнимательности и подумал что StopIteration нельзя использовать в исключениях :)